# Book about a group of adults and teenagers travel to every single planets in our solar system

Tags: story-identification, space, solar-system

I would like to ask if any of you know about a book about a group of adults and teenagers travel to every single planets in our solar system by an accident

At the beginning of the series, a group of people are invited to visit a scientist's place to see his high-tech spaceship which has the Cone shape. Then all by a sudden they activated it and it flew into space. They visited one by one of the planets Saturn, Jupiter, Mars, Venus, Mercury, ... 
In some planets they found different lifeforms and they have to figure out their language by the talent of the professor.

I still remember that the characters in the story are a teenager boy, the narrator, a mechanic, a professor who is good at linguistics and a young girl.

I read the Vietnamese translation in 1996 when I was 10 so the original one should be published before 1995.

Comment: By "[galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy)" do you mean "[solar system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_System)"? (Our galaxy has billions or trillions of planets.) Do you have any idea what the original language was? What kind of names do the characters have?

Comment: @Binh - Your use of English language astronomical words is flawed.  A star system or solar system is a star (or stars) and the planets that orbit them.  A galaxy is a vast group of star systems - tiny galaxies have about a million (1,000,000) star systems, gigantic galaxies have at least a trillion (1,000,000,000,000) stars.  The universe has  at least billions (1,000,000,000) of galaxies.  You say that they visit every single planet in our galaxy, and that they travel out into the universe, and then list the planets they visit that are all in our solar system.

Comment: Ha true, my bad. It should be solar system

Answer (score 2):

Could be [The Secret of the Ninth Planet](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?647665) by Donald A. Wollheim (1959)

Aliens are stealing the Sun's energy from every planet in the solar system. The teenage protagonist becomes charged with alien energy so only he can turn off the alien equipment. He is rushed to a secret government project where they have a cone-shaped antigravity spaceship (actually it is more shaped like an upside-down tear drop).

The expedition has to visit every planet in order to stop the alien's theft.

One mismatch: in the novel there are no young girls on the expedition. The crew is all adult men except for the teenage boy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately, it's not the fiction I'm looking for. And it's more about adventure